# Possible to move boot files?

Tags: linux, boot, directory-structure

I just bought an external hard drive that's 1TB. I formatted my laptop and burned Linux to it. The thing is, I also use my hard drive for other things. Can I move these boot files into a custom folder? Or should I leave them alone?

Comment: I'm confused....boot files are already in a seperate directory /boot.

Comment: This question is quite confusing. Is Linux installed in the laptop's internal hard drive or on the external one?

Comment: Linux is installed to the external drive which is 1TB. Obviously it will create boot files. Can I move them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you *would* want to move the /boot stuff. It *should* be possible, but it would break a lot of fundamental assumptions in boot-related tools.

One common thing that people do is store /boot on a separate partition, in which case /boot/boot should be a symlink to '.' so that when the bootloader mounts that partition, it still can access files under /boot.

That actually related to the underlying question, "I also use my hard drive for other things", which sounds like you might want a separate partition for that. But it's hard to be sure without knowing exactly what youwant to do